# How to use socket.io in app route

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, emit

I develop my first project with `nodejs`. I use `express 3` as framework and `socket.io` for the client server communication. At the moment I’m trying to create a register form. It works quite well, but I’m not sure how to use `socket.io` and `express` together correctly.

I check if the email and the password are valid, if they are not, I would like to push a json object the client.

I use this app route:

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body.user), 
        errors;

    function userSaveFailed() {
        res.render('index');
    }

    errors = user.validation(req.body.user.confirm);
    user.save(errors, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // Here I would like to send the Object to the client.
            io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
                socket.emit('registration', {
                    errors : errors
                });
            });
            return userSaveFailed();
        }
        res.render('user/new.jade');
    });
});
```

Well, the client gets the json object, but if another client connects to `'/'` he also gets the object. I guess I use the `socket.io` wrong. What’s the common way to use a `.emit()` in an app route? Is it necessary to use a global authorization for `socket.io` and `express` for this test?

Comment: why would you want to use socket.io to send back the error from a post.  In this case, I would just send the error via the reply.

Comment: Did you mean something like locals? `res.render('index', {locals: {errors : errors}});`? I used this to list the `errors` with `jade`, but how could I pass the json object to a javascript client function? Or whats is the common way to reply on a post?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do that (if you really want to use socket.io to reply to a post, which you probably shouldn't), is to use one room per user session.

so on the `on("connection", ...)` do something like so:

`socket.join(room)` where room is something unique to the session (like the session id for example).

then to send back to only one user:

`socketio.of('/')['in'](room).emit(...);`, room being that same unique id used above.